# Optimizing a MySQL query to avoid “Using temporary” and “Using filesort”

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I know there's a thousand similar questions out there, but I have been two weeks trying to find a real solution for this query.

This query comes from a Point of Sale program. This query is related to a form where the user chooses the report he needs (periods, totals, etc.) and whether or not want grouped results.

This is inconvenient. The query is generated in VB.NET, I mean, by code, and it will vary according to user's selections (different totals, periods, groups, etc.), so with the solution to this question I should be able to continue "creating" by code all other queries of the form.

In this case, this query is a totals query grouped by family.

Most of the time (>99%) is wasted in SENDING DATA (show profile for query #)

The tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `idProduct` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idFamily` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Codigo` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` char(70) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Nombre corto',
-- five more integer columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`),
  KEY `fk_p_idFamily` (`idFamily`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_p_idFamily` FOREIGN KEY (`idFamily`) REFERENCES `family`  (`idFamily`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19420 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0;

CREATE TABLE `family` (
  `idFamily` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `Descripcion` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Borrado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFamily`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0

CREATE TABLE `document` (
`idDocument` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Nombre` char(25) NOT NULL,
`Descripcion` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Borrado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NoComputa` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Rectifica` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CalculoSumatorioPVP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDocument`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0

CREATE TABLE `soldproduct` (
  `idProduct` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idSale` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PrecioCompra` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL ,
  `PrecioVenta` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL ,
  `DtoProd` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `BrutoUd` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL ,
  `PVPUd` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL ,
  `Cantidad` decimal(9,3) DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`,`idSale`),
  KEY `fk_pv_idSale` (`idSale`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pv_idProduct` FOREIGN KEY (`idProduct`) REFERENCES `product` (`idProduct`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pv_idSale` FOREIGN KEY (`idSale`) REFERENCES `sales` (`idSale`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0

CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `idSale` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDocument` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idEstadoVenta` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idCliente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idFormaPago` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idEmpleado` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL ,
  `idTienda` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTipoVenta` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FechaVenta` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de Venta',
  `PrecioCompraTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IVA` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- ten more decimal columns
  -- five more datetime columns
  -- ten more char columns
  `Borrado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `Historia` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVenta`),
  KEY `fk_v_idTienda` (`idTienda`),
  KEY `fk_v_idCliente` (`idCliente`),
  KEY `fk_v_idEmpleado` (`idEmpleado`),
  KEY `fk_v_idTipoVenta` (`idTipoVenta`),
  KEY `fk_v_idFormaPago` (`idFormaPago`),
  KEY `fk_v_idDocument` (`idDocument`),
  KEY `fk_v_idEstadoVenta` (`idEstadoVenta`),
  KEY `idx_v_FechaVenta` (`FechaVenta`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idCliente` FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`idCliente`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idDocument` FOREIGN KEY (`idDocument`) REFERENCES `document` (`idDocument`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idEmpleado` FOREIGN KEY (`idEmpleado`) REFERENCES `empleado` (`idEmpleado`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idEstadoVenta` FOREIGN KEY (`idEstadoVenta`) REFERENCES `estadoventa` (`idEstadoVenta`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idFormaPago` FOREIGN KEY (`idFormaPago`) REFERENCES `formapago` (`idFormaPago`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idTienda` FOREIGN KEY (`idTienda`) REFERENCES `tienda` (`idTienda`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_v_idTipoVenta` FOREIGN KEY (`idTipoVenta`) REFERENCES `tipoventa` (`idTipoVenta`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101770 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0
```

And the query is this:

```
SELECT  f.Nombre  ,SUM(sp.PrecioVenta*sp.Cantidad)  
FROM soldproduct sp, sales s, document doc, family f, product p 
WHERE s.idDocument = doc.idDocument AND doc.NoComputa = FALSE
AND p.idProduct = sp.idProduct AND sp.idSale = s.idSale 
AND p.idFamily = f.idFamily AND p.Borrado = FALSE 
AND s.Borrado = FALSE AND s.Historia = FALSE AND s.idTienda = 1 
AND s.FechaVenta BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' GROUP BY f.idFamily;
```

I've also try this one (I've also remove document table in case it is was responsible)

```
SELECT ProductFamily.Nombre, SUM(sp.PrecioVenta*sp.Cantidad) 
FROM 
(SELECT idSale FROM sales WHERE Borrado = FALSE AND Historia = FALSE AND idTienda = 1 
AND FechaVenta BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01') SalesidSale
JOIN
soldproduct sp
ON sp.idSale = SalesidSale.idSale
JOIN
(SELECT p.idProduct, p.idFamily, f.Nombre FROM product p, family f WHERE 
p.idFamily = f.idFamily AND p.Borrado = FALSE) ProductFamily
ON ProductFamily.idProduct = sp.idProduct
GROUP BY ProductFamily.idFamily;
```

The time it takes is very large, and its output to EXPLAIN command is (first query):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                               key                 key_len ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      v       range   PRIMARY,fk_v_idTienda,fk_v_idDocument,idx_v_FechaVenta      idx_v_FechaVenta    6       NULL                    7387    "Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE      doc     ALL     PRIMARY                                                     NULL                NULL    NULL                    4       "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
1   SIMPLE      pv      ref     PRIMARY,fk_pv_idSale                                        fk_pv_idSale        4       gemalia.s.idSale        4       NULL
1   SIMPLE      p       eq_ref  PRIMARY,fk_p_idFamily                                       PRIMARY             2       gemalia.sp.idProduct    1       "Using where"
1   SIMPLE      f       eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                     PRIMARY             1       gemalia.p.idFamily      1       NULL
```

I hope someone can help me, I tried to create indices, subqueries, etc.. but I can't get anything lower than 40 seconds, which is too much, and I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong..

The number of rows per table, is approximately:
Sales: 100,000
Products: 20,000
Families: 35
SoldProducts: 1,100,000
Documents: 4

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try playing with the clauses in `WHERE` in the first query.. ex try putting these conditions `p.Borrado = FALSE 
AND s.Borrado = FALSE AND s.Historia = FALSE AND s.idTienda = 1 ` first before join condition.

Comment: Hi Meherzad, are you saying about first query or second query ?

Comment: I've also try to do the query WITHOUT AGGREGATE FUNCTION and GROUP BY CLAUSE. The query time is , but the problem is Server has to send lofts of data (this is the real problem), and then, I'll have to "sum" them by code (less problematic). I've received 62458 rows. Query results: Duration (4.366 second) Fetch (174.852 seconds). I've seen something strange in "show profile output": the output is a sequence of "'Waiting for query cache lock'" (0 seconds) and "sending data" (2 or 3 seconds) and at the end, there is a final "sending data" of 40 seconds. May be something about server config ?

Comment: I've change this: innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M and innodb_log_file_size=250M.                                            Now, the query last 10 seconds, so it's good. Could be anything to improve it ? **Please, people with this kind of problems**, check innodb_buffer_pool_size and put 50% of your total ram.           ould be anything to improve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query in which we are trying to take advantage of short circuit.

**EDIT**

```
 SELECT  
   f.Nombre, 
   SUM(sp.PrecioVenta*sp.Cantidad)  
 FROM 
   soldproduct sp
 INNER JOIN 
   sales s
 ON 
   (s.idTienda = 1 AND AND 
   s.Borrado = FALSE AND 
   s.Historia = FALSE AND 
   sp.idSale = s.idSale)
 INNER JOIN
   document doc
 ON
   (doc.NoComputa = FALSE AND
   s.idDocument = doc.idDocument) 
 INNER JOIN
   family f
 ON
   (p.idFamily = f.idFamily) 
 INNER JOIN
   product p 
 ON
   (p.Borrado = FALSE AND         
   p.idProduct = sp.idProduct)
 WHERE 
   s.FechaVenta BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
 GROUP BY 
   f.idFamily;
```

Comment: Thanks, **but it doesn't work**. It's seems that in MySQL 5.6.10 (the version that I'm working on it) doesn't matter the order. EXPLAIN output is the same. The "sending data" time is wasting >99% of total time.

Comment: I've check it, it doesn't improve. I'm now in 10 seconds, after changing my.ini file.